# Values rotation in array with bash

Tags: arrays, linux, bash

I created a little script that allow to make a rotation of values in an array. 
The goal was to shift the values to the right and that the last value of the array became the first value in order to create a rotation.

The purpose of the exercice was to do it without using a temporary array but to create a temporary variable in which I can put one of the values of the array then shifted all values to the right and then, put the temporary variable in the array.

So, my script :

```
#!/bin/bash

declare -a array
empty=0


size()
        {
         read -p " How many box in you array ? : " size
        }



array_creation()        
        {
         counter=1
         while [ $counter -le $size ]
                do
                        array[$counter]=$counter
                        let "counter = counter + 1"
                done
        }

loop()
        {
         while [ $empty -eq 0 ]
         do

                clear
                echo "${array[*]}"

                tmp=$(echo "${array[$size]}")

                counter=$size

                while [ $counter -ge 2 ]
                        do
                                let " move = counter - 1" 
                                array[$counter]=$(echo "${array[$move]}") 
                                let "counter = counter - 1" 
                        done

                                array[1]=$tmp 
                                echo ""
                                loop_works
         done 
        }

loop_works() 
{   
 read -p " Press N to shift boxes  to the right : " add
 counter=$(($size + 1))
}   

size
array_creation
loop
```

When I press " n ", my script works perfectly but I'm not satisfied... I believe my script " too complex ", I made things very difficult for myself for this simple exercice...

Can you show how I can simplify my script ?

Thank you !

Comment: I think you should try asking on code review instead https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Please take a look at http://www.shellcheck.net/ to get some hints.

Comment: your code is good for a newbie, you seem to understand the major features of programming, i.e. iteration and conditional processing. There may be a dozen valid ways to code your problem in shell. "purpose was to use a temporary variable (not array).". Well come on, an array is just a type of variable, it allows for the storing of externally provided (variable) data in an easily accessible way. Use of arrays are something that will pay off mastering. Unless a grade is involved, don't sweat this. On to the next problem! Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

You can more easily do this with parameter expansion, which allows you to slice using `${array[@]:start:length}`:

```
#!/bin/bash
read -rp "Number of elements: " length
read -rp "Places to shift: " n
n=$((length-n))

array=( $(seq 1 "$length") )    
echo "Original: ${array[*]}"

array=( "${array[@]:n}" "${array[@]:0:n}" )
echo "Shifted: ${array[*]}"
```

Example:

```
$ ./myscript
Number of elements: 7
Places to shift: 2
Original: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7
Shifted: 6 7 1 2 3 4 5
```

Comment: Thank you for this exemple !

But for  this exercice, I have to remove a value from the array, put it in a temporary variable, shift all the variables to the right and then put back the variable that was extracted. Your method works great but it's like I'm using a temporary array, no ?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. There's only one array here.